# Modifying referencing and bibliography style on converted LaTeX file

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, bibtex

Zotero stuffed up my referencing, so I'm thinking to convert the `.odt` to `.tex` using the export feature of LibreOffice Writer.

When I export from LibreOffice Writer, I don't get a bibliography, and half the references are like:

```
\label{ref:ZOTEROITEMcitationID2cird4ma9fcitationItemsurihttpzoteroorgusers599343itemsTCC6K72BRNDVPoyfZpvsE}(Lin
and Lin).
```

Whilst the other half are like:

```
\footnote{Adobe Systems Incorporated (2000). \textit{PDF Reference: Adobe Portable Document Format: Version 1.3}. 2nd ed. Boston: Addison-Wesley. 485.}
```

Would I then be able to modify the referencing style from subscript Roman-numerals to (Author, Year), and generate a new bibliography in that style?

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: I've tried kind of answer but it's very general. A less general and more detailed answer may be possible if you would be able to generate a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) from an example export with reference and bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In LaTeX, the form separates from the content. In this case, the content is the references, the form is the style.

Bibliographic content is managed in bibTeX format files (usually with .bib extension). There is a commonly know format you can write on your own, or use a program with GUI which will do it for you. I personally use JabRef, but many others do. Also Google Scholar can be configured to export citation in bibTeX format, so do some other sites, where you can find/read papers.

The style is defined as you call the creation of your document. In this document you will find a declaration of style along with the declaration of the content to fetch.

```
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{Memoire}
```

You will find a list of commonly available styles on websites such as [this one](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html)

The references are identify in bibTeX files with what we call a key. This key is used in the TeX file along with the `\cite{KEY}` command. The key can be whatever you want, provided you can remember (or fetch) it when you need to cite something. The actual representation in the final document depends on the style you have chosen. So you can have long keys in your bibTeX file while the document will show them number from 1, or with full author name, or just initials etc.

And just for memory, you need to compile (`latex` or `pdflatex`) once your document to generate  the list of cited papers in auxiliary files, then call `bibtex` command to fetch the entries from bibTeX files to bbl files, then again compile twice your document to regenerated the reference references and include them in the paper. The `\nocite{*}` declaration can be use if you want to print out all the references in the bibTeX file without explicitly citing all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Note: The first part of this answer has been made, before at least two example lines have been part of the question.

Yes, but: The effort depends on the export and the export depends on the markup quality of your `.odt` file. Worst case would be, that all the references result in something like `$_{\textrm{XII}}$` or `\textsubscript{\textrm{XII}}` and the bibliography is a free formated list of what ever e.g.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[I] …
…
\item[XII] Author's Name: \emph{Title}, Date, Place
…
\end{itemize}
```

In this case you'd have to replace all of the references by something like `\cite{XII}` and either write a BibTeX database to use a package like [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) or you have to transform the free formated bibliography into a `thebibliography` enviroment like:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{XX}
\bibitem[XII]{Author's Name Date}: \emph{Title}, Place
\end{thebibliography}
```

In the last case using of `biblatex` would not be recommended, but usage of [natbib](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) may be a choice even with manual edited `thebibliography` instead of BibTeX database.

Now, after you've shown at least two examples lines of generated LaTeX code, I must say, the case is worse than expected. The first kind of entry

```
\label{ref:ZOTEROITEMcitationID2cird4ma9fcitationItemsurihttpzoteroorgusers599343itemsTCC6K72BRNDVPoyfZpvsE}(Lin and Lin)
```

is absolutely useless. You have to set a new `\cite{`*unique key*`}` and create either a new BibTeX database entry for this or a new `\bibitem` at a `thebibliography` environment.

The second kind:

```
\footnote{Adobe Systems Incorporated (2000). \textit{PDF Reference: Adobe portable Document Format: Version 1.3}. 2nd ed. Boston: Addison-Wesley. 485.}
```

is a little more usefull. You have to replace it by a new `\cite` too, but you may use the information from the footnote to make either a new BibTeX database entry or a new `\bibitem` at a `thebibliography` environment.

Here an example of a BibTeX database and the usage:

```
% First we generate the BibTeX-Database
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@manual { adobe2000,
  author = {{Adobe System Incorporated}},
  title = {PDF Reference: Adobe portable Document Format: Version 1.3},
  edition = {2nd},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Boston},
  year = 2000,
}
\end{filecontents*}
% Then we use it:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}% see <http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex>
\bibliography{demo}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\cite{adobe2000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You need to

1. run latex or pdflatex
2. run bibtex
3. run latex or pdflatex
4. run latex or pdflatex

After this a snapshot of the chapter with the reference would look like:

[image: snapshot of the chapter with the reference]

and a snapshot of the bibliography would look like:

[image: snapshot of the bibliography]

You may change the lookalike of both, reference and bibliography, using several settings of package [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

See also M'vy's answer for more information about separation of form and contents.

Comment: Thanks, actually with a bit of back-and-forth I should be able to change the roman-numerals (\footnote) citations to (Author, Year) with corrected bibliography also. How would I automate just the conversion of these footnotes?

Comment: @AT: If you are a programmer you may try to write a pearl script to do the automatic conversion. But at least if there are other footnotes too or if the variety of the reference footnotes is large(?) it may be at least as much manual work as doing it completely manual.

Comment: Thanks, ended up fixing up all the Citations by adding them manually to Zotero. For my next paper, I will write with LaTeX from the start.